# How to remove space in String

Tags: asp.net

String prod="pizza cafe",i want to print "PizzaCafe" .How to do that in Asp.net?i want to minimize space between pizza and cafe?

String abc=TextBox1.Text;
if TextBox1.Text="pizza cafe",i want to convert it to "PizzaCafe" 
 row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "name", Value = TextBox1.Text });

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Comment: trying search on google is much faster than posting the question.

Comment: And maybe... read about regex ;)

Comment: So you want to remove spaces and "title-case" all words?

    `var ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
    string text = "pizza cafe";
    var newWords = text.Split().Select(w => ti.ToTitleCase(w));
    string newText = string.Join("", newWords);`

Answer (score 0):

```
abc.Replace(" ", string.empty);
```